# You need me; I can frighten you. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> You need me everyday and admire my beauty
>   Yet you are afraid of me as verb and verb and noun
>   Humans need me to survive
>   Whether they are camping in forest or living in town
>
> You make me many times a day and make me die
>   Sometimes I am silent and sometimes I cry
>
> Some believe I am one of the world's basic elements
>   Some worship me or use me to worship while uttering chants

***Who am I?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it

> Fire

You need me everyday and admire my beauty

> Fire is beautiful

Yet you are afraid of me as verb and verb and noun

> Don't want to get fired, and fire is dangerous

Humans need me to survive

> Not strictly needed, but fire helps to survive

Whether they are camping in forest or living in town

> Need for cooking, warmth, defence, etc.

You make me many times a day and make me die

> We turn our stoves/cars/lighters on and off during the day

Some times I am silent and sometimes I cry

> a flame can be silent or make noise

Some believe I am one of the world's basic element

> one of four basic elements earth, wind, water, fire

Some worship me or use me to worship while uttering chant

> fire is used in many religious rituals

Comment: That was quick. Nice one

Comment: Can you explain the "you are afraid of me as verb and verb and noun" part?

Comment: @colmde 'fire' as a verb means to lose one's job, something most people don't like.  'fire' as a noun is fire.